# C++ passing Vector character pointer by reference

Tags: c++, reference, vector, chat, constants

Hi every one I have the following problem I need to build a vector array from a file.
I managed to creat a vector by reading the file into a string buffer then saving it into this following vector.

```
vector<char> pattern(contents.begin(), contents.end());
```

But I have the following function that I need to pass the vector to.

```
void WuManber::Initialize( const vector<const char *> &patterns, 
                      bool bCaseSensitive, bool bIncludeSpecialCharacters, bool bIncludeExtendedAscii )
```

how can I read from a file a passable vector to this function.
thank you for your help.

to elaborate more I need it to do the following

```
for ( size_t q = m; q >= B; --q ) 
  { // start loop -8-

  unsigned int hash;
  hash  = m_lu[patterns[j][q - 2 - 1]].offset; // bring in offsets of X in pattern j
  hash <<= m_nBitsInShift;
  hash += m_lu[patterns[j][q - 1 - 1]].offset;
  hash <<= m_nBitsInShift;
  hash += m_lu[patterns[j][q     - 1]].offset;
  size_t shiftlen = m - q;
  m_ShiftTable[ hash ] = min( m_ShiftTable[ hash ], shiftlen );
  if ( 0 == shiftlen ) 
 {  // start if -8-
    m_PatternMapElement.ix = j;
    m_PatternMapElement.PrefixHash = m_lu[patterns[j][0]].offset;
    m_PatternMapElement.PrefixHash <<= m_nBitsInShift;
    m_PatternMapElement.PrefixHash += m_lu[patterns[j][1]].offset;
    m_vPatternMap[ hash ].push_back( m_PatternMapElement );
  } // end if -8-

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
if (argc < 2) {
  std::cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << " <filename>\n";
  return 2;
 }

 ifstream fin(argv[1]);
 if (fin) {
  stringstream ss;
  // this copies the entire contents of the file into the string stream
  ss << fin.rdbuf();
  // get the string out of the string stream
  string contents = ss.str();
  cout << contents;
  // construct the vector from the string.
  vector<char> pattern(contents.begin(), contents.end());
  Initialize( &pattern);
  cout << pattern.size();
 }
 else {
  cout << "Couldn't open " << argv[1] << "\n";
  return 1;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What vector do you want to pass to that function? It expects a vector of *pointers*.

Comment: How is the contents of your file and the patterns parameter related?  Is each line of your file supposed to be one pattern?

Comment: yes each line in the file is a pattern

Comment: I need it to do the following I have a large patterns file that I have to create a hash table from so it would be waste if I not passed it by reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is looking for a `vector` of C strings (that's the most likely meaning of `const char *` inside a container named `patterns`.

Here is how you can build one:

```
std::vector<const char*> patterns;
patterns.push_back("my-first-pattern");
patterns.push_back("my-second-pattern");
```

If you or your team designed this function, you may want to suggest changing the container type to a more C++ - ish `vector<string>`.

If you are reading your patterns from a file, you can populate your array as follows:

**EDIT** (in response to a comment)

```
std::ifstream ifs("file_with_patterns.txt");
std::vector<const char*> patterns;
while (!ifs.eof()) {
    std::string buf;
    std::getline(ifs, buf);
    patterns.push_back(strdup(buf.c_str()));
}
```

Comment: @user1231229 What's the error that you are getting? Did you include all required headers? You need `string`, `vector`, `fstream`, `iterator`, and `algorithm`.

Comment: Test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
Test.cpp:16:11: error: ‘istream_iterator’ is not a member of ‘std’
Test.cpp:16:44: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
Test.cpp:16:52: error: ‘istream_iterator’ is not a member of ‘std’
Test.cpp:16:85: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
Test.cpp:16:87: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token

Comment: @user1231229 Are you including the `<iterator>` header? This is where `std::istream_iterator` is declared.

Comment: thank you it compiled and everything but the spaces that are read from text file are considered as a new line I want the whole line saved with its spaces.

Comment: example (x y x) one line / but it is saved pattern[0] =x ,pattern[1] = y ,patter[2] = z , I want it to be save pattern [0] = x y z

Comment: thanks very much for your help may I ask a question.. how do you know so much, I want to learn, more to be like you.

Comment: @user1231229 Don't worry, you will learn a lot, it just takes time and practice. It took me more than 25 years of programming to learn what I know. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If `contents` is a `std::string`, you can store a pointer to the `string`'s data inside a vector and pass it to the function:

```
vector<const char*> patterns;
patterns.push_back(contents.c_str());

// then pass patterns to Initialise

Initialise(patterns, bool, bool, bool);

// make sure you do not try to use `patterns` after you have changed `contents`
```

Comment: He can do that with a `vector<char>` also, using `push_back(&contents[0])`, no need for a `string`.

Comment: @BenVoigt it would be pointless to put a string into a vector then put that vector into another vector when he could just put the string into the vector directly.

Comment: I thought from the question that it came to him in a `vector<char>`.  Now I see that may just have been a failed attempt to do what you explained.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but maybe instead of void, make it a vector and return modified vector back?

```
vector<char> WuManber::Initialize(const vector<const char *> &patterns, bool bCaseSensitive, bool bIncludeSpecialCharacters, bool bIncludeExtendedAscii ) 
{
 //vector manupilations
 return patterns;
}
```